# Which type i should provide to pass props to component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I have component where i map each item from store array

```
{this.state.figures
   .sort(( a, b ) => a > b ? 1 : -1 )
   .reverse()
   .map((item: ***ItemProps***) => {
       return (
          <Item key={Math.random()} data={item}/>
       );
})}
```

And my component

```
type ItemProps = {
    data: {
        name: string;
        sprites: {
            front_default: string;
        }
    }
}

const Item = (props: ItemProps): JSX.Element => {
    const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure()

    return (
        {/* ... */}
    )
}

export default Item
```

The problem in type item in MAP, which type should i use?

Comment: What's the type for `this.state.figures`?

Comment: this.state = {
      limit: 12,
      count: 0,
      pages: 0,
      error: false,
      figures: [],
      offset: 0,
      loaded: false,
      currentPage: Number(props.currentPage),
      navigate: props.navigate,
};

Comment: What's the content for `figures`?

Comment: I have figures with type array, fetch data add push results from requests after i need to map this array and each item pass to component

Comment: You need to specify the type for `figures`, otherwise you won't be able to type `item` inside map.

Comment: what type of array do i need to specify for figures so that it can store multiple objects?

Comment: You need to explicitly tell TS which type of objects will be stored in the array.